# Getting javascript postback parameters with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following element:

```
<a class="html-attribute-value html-external-link" target="_blank" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ResultsGrid$15", "", false, "", "webproperty.aspx?s=id&amp;s=15&amp;time=201606080118012&amp", false, true))'>javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&amp;quot;ucResultsGrid$R000000015&amp;quot;, &amp;quot;&amp;quot;, false, &amp;quot;&amp;quot;, &amp;quot;webprop.aspx?s=id&amp;amp;sr=15&amp;amp;time=201606080118012&amp;amp;id=15&amp;quot;, false, true))</a>
```

I want to get the javascript parameters to try to reconstruct the request produced by clicking on a link. I've found that:

```
response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="ResultsGrid$15"]/@href').extract()

Out[20]: [u'javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ResultsGrid$15", "", false, "", "webproperty.aspx?s=id&sdata=15&time=201606080037034&id=15", false, true))']
```

This looks good and decodes the javascript parameters. How do I grab them from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via [`re()` method](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions) and multiple capturing groups:

```
response.selector.xpath('//*[@id="ResultsGrid$15"]/@href').re(r'javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions\(new WebForm_PostBackOptions\("(.*?)", "(.*?)", (.*?), "(.*?)", "(.*?)", (.*?), (.*?)\)\)')
```

Here I'm using a quite broad `.*?` - *non-greedy* match for any characters any number of times, but you can be more strict about what characters to match in what parameter.